# cannot perform dml operation inside a query in plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql

Here in this below function i want to insert values into table ba_acct_cust_lob_xref according to account number and customer id. And account number im fetching from ch_acct_mast table and customer id from cl_custmast table. How i can achieve this using plsql function. when i tried it is showing error like cannot perform dml opertaion inside a query.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION AP_EXT_MNT_BAM62
(
        var_typ_entity              CHAR,
        var_cod_acct_no             CHAR,
        var_cod_cust_id             NUMBER,
        var_cod_ao_business         varchar2,
        var_cod_ao_operations       varchar2,
        var_cod_lob                 NUMBER

)
RETURN NUMBER
AS

BEGIN
       
        IF var_typ_entity = 'A' THEN
    BEGIN
            insert into ba_cust_acct_ao_lob_xref
            (typ_entity,
            Cod_cust_id,
            cod_acct_no,
            Cod_ao_business,
            cod_ao_operations,
            cod_lob,
            flg_mnt_status,
            cod_mnt_action,
            cod_last_mnt_makerid,
            cod_last_mnt_chkrid,
            dat_last_mnt,
            ctr_updat_srlno,
            COD_ENTITY_VPD)
            (select var_typ_entity,
            var_cod_cust_id,
            var_cod_acct_no,
            var_cod_ao_business,
            var_cod_ao_operations,
            var_cod_lob,
            flg_mnt_status,
            cod_mnt_action,
            cod_last_mnt_makerid,
            cod_last_mnt_chkrid,
            sysdate,
            ctr_updat_srlno,
            COD_ENTITY_VPD
            from CH_ACCT_MAST
            where cod_acct_no=var_cod_acct_no );
        
        EXCEPTION
        when no_data_found then
      NULL;        
          END;
        END IF;
        
        IF var_typ_entity = 'C' THEN
    BEGIN
            insert into ba_cust_acct_ao_lob_xref
            (typ_entity,
            Cod_cust_id,
            cod_acct_no,
            Cod_ao_business,
            cod_ao_operations,
            cod_lob,
            flg_mnt_status,
            cod_mnt_action,
            cod_last_mnt_makerid,
            cod_last_mnt_chkrid,
            dat_last_mnt,
            ctr_updat_srlno,
            COD_ENTITY_VPD)
            (select var_typ_entity,
            var_cod_cust_id,
            var_cod_acct_no,
            var_cod_ao_business,
            var_cod_ao_operations,
            var_cod_lob,
            flg_mnt_status,
            cod_mnt_action,
            cod_last_mnt_makerid,
            cod_last_mnt_chkrid,
            sysdate,
            ctr_updat_srlno,
            COD_ENTITY_VPD
            from CI_CUSTMAST
            where Cod_cust_id=var_Cod_cust_id );
        
        EXCEPTION
        when no_data_found then
      NULL;        
          END;
        END IF;
    return 1;


END;
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you *can* perform DML in a function and use it in a query, if it were an autonomous transaction. Don't do that, not here.

Here's an example, using this sample table:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM test;

        ID NAME
---------- --------------------
         2 Little
         3 Foot
```

Function is supposed to insert a row into that table (basically, that's what you have):

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_test (par_id IN NUMBER, par_name IN VARCHAR2)
  2     RETURN NUMBER
  3  IS
  4  BEGIN
  5     INSERT INTO test (id, name)
  6          VALUES (par_id, par_name);
  7
  8     RETURN 1;
  9  END;
 10  /

Function created.
```

Error you got is due to such a code:

```
SQL> SELECT f_test (5, 'Karthiga') FROM DUAL;
SELECT f_test (5, 'Karthiga') FROM DUAL
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-14551: cannot perform a DML operation inside a query
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.F_TEST", line 5
```

If it were a PL/SQL procedure, then your function *would* work:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     l_test  NUMBER;
  3  BEGIN
  4     l_test := f_test (5, 'Karthiga');
  5  END;
  6  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Or, as I previously said, if function was an autonomous transaction, you could use it in a query:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_test (par_id IN NUMBER, par_name IN VARCHAR2)
  2     RETURN NUMBER
  3  IS
  4     PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
  5  BEGIN
  6     INSERT INTO test (id, name)
  7          VALUES (par_id, par_name);
  8
  9     COMMIT;
 10     RETURN 1;
 11  END;
 12  /

Function created.


SQL> SELECT f_test (7, 'Twitter') FROM DUAL;

F_TEST(7,'TWITTER')
-------------------
                  1

SQL>
```

See? Now it works, but that's not what you should be doing, really.

Result:

```
SQL> select * from test;

        ID NAME
---------- --------------------
         2 Little
         3 Foot
         5 Karthiga      --> newly added
         7 Twitter       --> rows

SQL>
```

---

Why do you insist on a function? This is obviously a **procedure** code. Yes, you're returning `1` *just because* function has to return *something*, but there's no evidence that you do need a function. Functions *calculate* stuff and return the value. You're just inserting a row; that's what procedures do.

So:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE AP_EXT_MNT_BAM62 (
   var_typ_entity         CHAR,
   var_cod_acct_no        CHAR,
   var_cod_cust_id        NUMBER,
   var_cod_ao_business    VARCHAR2,
   var_cod_ao_operations  VARCHAR2,
   var_cod_lob            NUMBER)
AS
BEGIN
   IF var_typ_entity = 'A'
   THEN
      BEGIN
         INSERT INTO ba_cust_acct_ao_lob_xref (typ_entity,
                                               Cod_cust_id,
                                               cod_acct_no,
                                               Cod_ao_business,
                                               cod_ao_operations,
                                               cod_lob,
                                               flg_mnt_status,
                                               cod_mnt_action,
                                               cod_last_mnt_makerid,
                                               cod_last_mnt_chkrid,
                                               dat_last_mnt,
                                               ctr_updat_srlno,
                                               COD_ENTITY_VPD)
            (SELECT var_typ_entity,
                    var_cod_cust_id,
                    var_cod_acct_no,
                    var_cod_ao_business,
                    var_cod_ao_operations,
                    var_cod_lob,
                    flg_mnt_status,
                    cod_mnt_action,
                    cod_last_mnt_makerid,
                    cod_last_mnt_chkrid,
                    SYSDATE,
                    ctr_updat_srlno,
                    COD_ENTITY_VPD
               FROM CH_ACCT_MAST
              WHERE cod_acct_no = var_cod_acct_no);
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
         THEN
            NULL;
      END;
   END IF;

   IF var_typ_entity = 'C'
   THEN
      BEGIN
         INSERT INTO ba_cust_acct_ao_lob_xref (typ_entity,
                                               Cod_cust_id,
                                               cod_acct_no,
                                               Cod_ao_business,
                                               cod_ao_operations,
                                               cod_lob,
                                               flg_mnt_status,
                                               cod_mnt_action,
                                               cod_last_mnt_makerid,
                                               cod_last_mnt_chkrid,
                                               dat_last_mnt,
                                               ctr_updat_srlno,
                                               COD_ENTITY_VPD)
            (SELECT var_typ_entity,
                    var_cod_cust_id,
                    var_cod_acct_no,
                    var_cod_ao_business,
                    var_cod_ao_operations,
                    var_cod_lob,
                    flg_mnt_status,
                    cod_mnt_action,
                    cod_last_mnt_makerid,
                    cod_last_mnt_chkrid,
                    SYSDATE,
                    ctr_updat_srlno,
                    COD_ENTITY_VPD
               FROM CI_CUSTMAST
              WHERE Cod_cust_id = var_Cod_cust_id);
      EXCEPTION
         WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
         THEN
            NULL;
      END;
   END IF;
END;
```

If it *must* return `1`, then make it an OUT parameter.